# DB2 Data Extraction

Tags: sql, db2

I have a file in the bellow format called BAIMTHP in our library.

I want to extract the lines related 50K (For REF_NO 12345, ROW# 1,2 & 3. For REF_# 56789, ROW# 7,8,9 & 10). Issue is that the TAG field will not populate for all the rows instead the ROW_NO will be populating. I tried the bellow SQL but I was able to extract only the 1st row of the TAG field. In this case ROW_NO 1 and 7.

**Since images are not allowed to upload for my profile, I had to type the sample file details**

```
TEF_NO     TAG           ROW_#     ADDRESS
12345         50K          1                29/1
12345                      2               Ahamath Lane
12345                      3               Colombo
56789         50K          7               No 11
56789                      8               17th Lane
56789                      9               Colpitty
56789                      10             Colombo
```

Is there a way to do this in DB2?

```
CREATE TABLE QTEMP. TEST AS (SELECT * FROM EMOQRYLIB.BAIMTHP WHERE TAG = '50K')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
CREATE TABLE QTEMP.TEST AS 
    SELECT *
    FROM EMOQRYLIB.BAIMTHP b
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM EMOQRYLIB.BAIMTHP b2
                  WHERE b2.tef_no = b.tef_no AND b2.TAG = '50K'
                 );
```

Comment: What happens in the bellow? Won't it again give me only the row where TAG 50K available?                                              (SELECT 1                   FROM EMOQRYLIB.BAIMTHP b2                   WHERE b2.tef_no = b.tef_no AND b2.TAG = '50K'                  );

Comment: @ShabeenZarook . . . No, it will give you all `tef_no`s that have at least one row with the tag equal to `'50K'`.

Comment: I'll check and revert if I hit a dead end as the requirements is to extract the ADDRESS column.